# JQuery change part of the image url with select

Tags: jquery, image, html-select, src

I've searched all over the internet, find some smilair options but it's not exactly what I want...

I have some dropdown options with a color code and I want my customers to change the color of the image,  but in parts. In this situation I have 2 color options, sometimes I have 6.

So if I select color "0000ff"

```
<select name="color1">
  <option>ff0000</option>
  <option>ffff00</option>
  <option>0000ff</option>
  <option selected="selected">00ffff</option>
```

I need the script to change the first color of the image.

```
<img src="http://www.ballonnenkoerier.nl/beta/image/catalog/merge.php?color1=ff6600&color2=ff0066"/>
```

The script I use is not made for this but gives me a base... where I got stuck..

I hope someone will help me. I've made a JSFiddle to make it easier:

http://jsfiddle.net/9q5Lcsa3/1/

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: Kevin is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/9q5Lcsa3/8/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9q5Lcsa3/2/).

```
$("select")
    .change(function()
    {
        var str = "http://www.ballonnenkoerier.nl/beta/image/catalog/merge.php?",
            i = 0;
        $("select option:selected").each(function()
        {
            i++;
            str += 'color' + i + '=' + $(this).text() + '&';
        });
        str = str.replace(/&$/, '');
        $("span").text(str);
    })
    .change();
```

Comment: Add id="foo" to your image and add: $('#foo').attr('src', str); to the script

Answer (score 0):

### [**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9q5Lcsa3/8/)

You need something like this.

```
$("select").change(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    var arr = $(this).map(function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get().map(function(x){
        return "color" + (++counter) + "=" + x;
    });
    $('img').attr('src', function (_, src) {
        return src.replace(/\?.*/,"?") + arr.join("&");
    });
});
```